# Using .NET Core to build a dynamic controller at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to web service that allows you to add/amend the controller code on the fly without recompiling.

I've found a way of doing this using a DefaultHttpControllerSelector, but this doesn't work in .NET core.  I've also found of doing something similar using  IApplicationModelConvention, but this only allows you to add new controllers at startup.  Using the DefaultHttpControllerSelector you could do the whole thing without recompiling.
(Example below taken from https://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/leveraging-roslyn-to-author-asp-net-web-api-without-recompiling/)

```
public class NoCacheSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;
private const string Controllers = @"C:UsersFilipDocumentsVisual Studio 2012ProjectsMvcApplication6MvcApplication6Controllers";
private const string Models = @"C:UsersFilipDocumentsVisual Studio 2012ProjectsMvcApplication6MvcApplication6Models";

public NoCacheSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var controllers = Directory.GetFiles(Controllers);
    var models = Directory.GetFiles(Models);
    var metadataReferences = controllers.Select(i => SyntaxTree.ParseFile(i)).Union(models.Select(i => SyntaxTree.ParseFile(i)));

    var compiledCode = Compilation.Create(
        outputName: "controllersAndModels.dll",
        options: new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
        syntaxTrees: metadataReferences,
        references: new[] { 
            new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location), 
            new MetadataFileReference(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location), 
            new MetadataFileReference(typeof(ApiController).Assembly.Location), 
     });

    Assembly assembly;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        compiledCode.Emit(stream);
        assembly = Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer());
    }

    var types = assembly.GetTypes();
    var matchedTypes = types.Where(i =&gt; typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(i)).ToList();

    var controllerName = base.GetControllerName(request);
    var matchedController = matchedTypes.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.ToLower() == controllerName.ToLower() + "controller");

    return new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, matchedController);
}
}
```